# web2py-sqlform can't check unique=True that use with requires=IS_LENGTH()

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, web2py

sqlform don't show error message when data have same value it accepted then error appear 
[error1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g6G4B.jpg)
[detail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iuvnW.jpg)
ps. my goal is to create a field that contain 13 figure number which not same as other

i try delete requires=IS_LENGTH(maxsize=13,minsize=13) then the sqlform work fine but which these method i can't check either string is equal 13 or not

```
db.define_table('person',
Field('h_id_card',unique=True,requires=IS_LENGTH(maxsize=13,minsize=13))
)
```

```
def add():
form = SQLFORM(db.person).process()
    return locals()
```

i expected sqlform will show error message instead of accepted

[this is what i expect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mRqyl.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

From the [book](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/06/the-database-abstraction-layer#Field-types):

> Notice that `requires=...` is enforced at the level of forms, `required=True` is enforced at the level of the DAL (insert), while `notnull`, `unique` and `ondelete` are enforced at the level of the database. While they sometimes may seem redundant, it is important to maintain the distinction when programming with the DAL.

Because `unique=True` translates to the `UNIQUE` SQL statement, when an insert/update violates the uniqueness constraint, you simply get an error from the database, which generates an exception in the database driver, which ultimately generates an exception in your app code if you don't catch it.

If you instead want to enable form validation for the uniqueness requirement, you should use the [`IS_NOT_IN_DB` validator](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/07/forms-and-validators#Database-validators):

```
Field('h_id_card',
      requires=[IS_LENGTH(maxsize=13, minsize=13), IS_NOT_IN_DB(db, 'person.h_id_card')])
```

Comment: +1 it works many thank to you Anthony. I am a beginner with 0 year of experience. Therefore my question might be strength to you